# No constant polynomials are irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra

No constant polynomials are irreducible?

What does it mean?

Is it because constant polynomials are units?

Comment: We need to be more careful with the term "constant polynomial". It could reasonably mean either a degree 0 polynomial, or a polynomial which, as a function of the elements of the ring, is constant. For example, $x^2+x+1\in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is irreducible and constantly evaluates to $1,$ so you could call that a constant polynomial that is irreducible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're correct, **if working over a field**; that is, if the polynomial ring you're talking about is $F[x]$ where $F$ is a field, then any non-zero constant polynomial is a **unit** of the ring $F[x]$, and the constant zero polynomial is the **zero element** of the ring $F[x]$, and therefore none of them are irreducible elements of $F[x]$, simply because [the definition of "irreducible" excludes such elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element).

However, if the polynomial ring is $R[x]$ where $R$ is a ring that is not a field, then there may be non-zero constant polynomials that are irreducible elements of $R[x]$. For example, in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the element $2$ is a constant polynomial that is irreducible.