# Non-singular Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the space of polynomial functions over $\mathbb{R}$

Can we give an example of a linear operator $T$ on $V$ such that $T$ is non-singular and non-invertible?

Comment: If a linear operator is singular, it's not invertible; and if it's non-sigular, the operator is necessarily invertible, so there's no such example (over any vector space) - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42649/why-are-invertible-matrices-called-non-singular?rq=1).

Comment: your statement is true for finite dimensional!

Comment: Multiplication by any non-zero polynomial.

Comment: @Bernard non-constant

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the transformation on $R[X]$ given by

$$T\left(\sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^{i}\right) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{c_i}{1+i}x^{1+i}.$$

Then $T$ is non-singular (because its kernel is $0$) and non-invertible (because $1$ has no pre-image).

N.B.: $R[X]$ is infinite dimensional.